# Retrieving GCE Instance metadata.in Java

Tags: google-compute-engine

Can someone point me to how I retrieve the current instance's metadata from a java application that is deployed on a compute instance.

I'm looking to perform something similar to that of what the below AWS utility class does -
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/regions/internal/util/EC2MetadataUtils.html

Any pointers to GCP API/code samples would be helpful.

Thanks.
Siv

Comment: I found the below that uses making a REST call to fetch metadata, but I'd like to understand whether there is any java SDK support to achieve the same.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values

Answer (score 0):

You can use [APIs and Java libraries](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference) available on the services that you are using on your application. For your specific case, you can check it under the [Compute Engine Libraries](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-compute/latest/com/google/cloud/compute/v1/Metadata.html).